# IntelliJ - Large File Unbearably Slow To Load

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am trying to load a big java file autogenerated by Thrift (around 240,000 lines, 7.5mb). I am getting an error message "File size exceeds configured limit (2560000). Code insight features are not available." Now I know I'm supposed to go to the idea.properties file and change the line

> idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500

to a big number. However, if I enable Code insight for this file, it is unbearably slow to load and to scroll. If I don't enable Code insight, my project will not recognize this file during compilation. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Compile this file to a .jar and add the .jar file as a library to your project.

Comment: Doesn't have to bar a jar - it can simply be a `class` that is included in the compile/run time classpath. But this is certainly the way to do it.

Comment: It can be a .class file, but I'm personally not a fan of random .class files lying around. Jars are more tidy. :)

Comment: I'm just not sure the OP knows how to create a jar. You're right of course - if one were doing it properly one would also install it into a Maven repo; but it all gets very complex for a beginner...

Comment: @yole Is there any other way besides modification or creation of files? It is the core component and many of our microservices in our architecture depend on it. I am looking for a solution more related to an option in IntelliJ. I recently switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and although IntelliJ is a lot better in terms of functionality, Eclipse was faster when handling these large source files.

Comment: Try upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 14. If I remember correctly, it will correctly compile other files referencing the large file, even though you still won't be able to use code insight features for working with this file.

Comment: @exyrion please please read [F5 is not a build process](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process/). You IDE is a **development** environment; you should have a separate **build** process.